# Pandas and Python3.4 co existing with Python 2.7

Tags: pandas, python-3.4

I have pandas installed with python2.7. I also have python 3.4 installed.

I can't load pandas in python3

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
>>>
```

I understand I need to install it separately. How do I go about having pandas in both python 2.7 and 3.4 ? I am using a mac by the way.

Comment: I assume you installed pandas with pip. You have to use pip for python 3.4 if you want to install pandas for python 3.4

Comment: Yes I did install pandas with pip. How do I use pip for python 3.4 ?

Comment: How did you install pip the first time? You did `python ezsetup.py install`, presumably. Well, ensure that `python` in that case points to python 3.4. If you plan on switch python versions frequently, I would recommend installing pyenv to help manage versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find that you have a script called "pip3" on you system as python3.4 bundles pip in along side of python.

```
$ pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out.

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fine answers above, please note that pandas 0.24.x releases will be the last to support Python 2!
[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html)

Quote:
"Warning The 0.24.x series of releases will be the last to support Python 2. Future feature releases will support Python 3 only"

So, co-existence, it seems, would be limited to the 0.24.x version as a common version for both python 2 and 3.